# Cannot bind to Radius Networks Android IBeacon service

Tags: ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

So, I have just build and demonstrated the free Radius Networks IBeacon Android library. Working perfectly for me.

I have just ported over the code to my own app and updated the followinG:

- Updated Manifest to specify BLUETOOTH & BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions
- I have a FragmentActivity implement IBeaconConsumer (Overriding onIBeaconServiceConnect)
- My Android project references the AndroidIBeaconLibrary project from Radius Networks
- My project build target is OpenMobile API (with service layer) from G&D, Android API Level 18

In my application I am not ever getting a callback through IBeacon consumer.. Why is that?

Is there somekind of protection mechanism in the IBeacon library around other apps binding to service. i.e same package name etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your code that does the binding to the iBeaconManager?  Also, can you verify that you have manifest merging enabled?

Comment: Hi, that appeared to be the issue. Updating project.properties broke the build. I had to take the service definitions from your library project.. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the Radius Networks IBeacon Android service was not registered.

as David pointed out the manifests of the the library project and application project needed to be merged.

To merge manifests you must add the following line to project.properties file of application project.

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

For me, that did not work so I took the contents of the library projects manifest and put them in the manifest of the application project.

All is working now.